# How to sequentially run sql scripts (oracle) automatically using python?

Tags: python, sql, oracle

How to sequentially run daily SQL scripts (Oracle) automatically using python?
And also there are dependencies in the scripts as an example To run script B Script A wants to finish the execution.
Is that possible to do with python? - If possible, How can I do it automatically?

Thank you.

Comment: Why does it have to be with Python?  When your only tool is a hammer, every problem looks like a nail.  I would not want a tradesman whose toolbox contains only a hammer.

Comment: On the other hand, using Python to execute SQL statements allows better flow control, IO, error handling, as well as access to Oracle high availability features.  You can use `executemany()` to improve performance of data loads or changes. Instead of creating 'SQL scripts', create the statements in a form that can be run in Python.  If you must use some form of SQL file, then make it easier to work with by standardizing on the statement terminator and use something like this to read and execute statements: https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/SampleEnv.py#L116-L149

Answer (score 0):

Just use Oracle and set up a [chain of scheduled jobs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/scheduse.htm#ADMIN10021) where Job B is dependent on Job A having finished.

From the same documentation, [an example is](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/schedadmin.htm#ADMIN12069):

> ```sql
> BEGIN
>   DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_CHAIN (
>    chain_name            =>  'my_chain1',
>    rule_set_name         =>  NULL,
>    evaluation_interval   =>  NULL,
>    comments              =>  NULL);
> END;
> /
>  
> --- define three steps for this chain. Referenced programs must be enabled.
> BEGIN
>  DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_CHAIN_STEP('my_chain1', 'stepA', 'my_program1');
>  DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_CHAIN_STEP('my_chain1', 'stepB', 'my_program2');
>  DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_CHAIN_STEP('my_chain1', 'stepC', 'my_program3');
> END;
> /
>
> --- define corresponding rules for the chain.
> BEGIN
>  DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_CHAIN_RULE('my_chain1', 'TRUE', 'START stepA');
>  DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_CHAIN_RULE (
>    'my_chain1', 'stepA COMPLETED', 'Start stepB, stepC');
>  DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_CHAIN_RULE (
>    'my_chain1', 'stepB COMPLETED AND stepC COMPLETED', 'END');
> END;
> /
>
> --- enable the chain
> BEGIN
>  DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE('my_chain1');
> END;
> /
>
> --- create a chain job to start the chain daily at 1:00 p.m.
> BEGIN
>  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
>    job_name        => 'chain_job_1',
>    job_type        => 'CHAIN',
>    job_action      => 'my_chain1',
>    repeat_interval => 'freq=daily;byhour=13;byminute=0;bysecond=0',
>    enabled         => TRUE);
> END;
> /
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The utility [run_all_sql_dir.py](https://github.com/dmitrydemin1973/python_sqlplus/blob/main/run_all_sql_dir.py) executes all sql files from the specified directory and creates one log files. You can add this utility to your operating system's scheduler. In the script you can change the NLS settings, AUTOCOMMIT and silent mode sqlplus.

```
NLS_DATE_FORMAT = "\'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS\'"
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = "\'.,\'"
AUTO_COMMIT = "OFF"
NLS_LANG = 'AMERICAN_AMERICA.CL8MSWIN1251'
# silent sqlplus = "-s"  silent off sqlplus = ""
silent_sqlplus = "-s"
```

-u Specify the username for example SCOTT

-p Specify the password for example TIGER

-c Specify the connect_string(TNS alias) or easy connect string for connect to oracle database

-d Specify the directory for executing sql scripts.

-l Specify the logfile for output log.

For example

```
run_all_sql_dir.py -u scott -p tiger -c 192.168.0.166:1521/test -d C:\Users\Dmitry\PycharmProjects\count_char\sql  -l log_sql.log


import os
import subprocess
import pathlib
from optparse import OptionParser
import logging

NLS_DATE_FORMAT = "\'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS\'"
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = "\'.,\'"
AUTO_COMMIT = "OFF"
NLS_LANG = 'AMERICAN_AMERICA.CL8MSWIN1251'

Sqlheader = """
set autocommit """ + AUTO_COMMIT + "\n" + """set define off
set timing on
set linesize 10000
set pagesize 10000
set pause off
set echo on
set heading on
set termout ON
SET FEEDBACK ON
SET TAB ON
SET UNDERLINE ON
set trimspool on
""" + "ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = " + NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS + ";" + """
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = """ + NLS_DATE_FORMAT + ";\n"

parser = OptionParser(usage="usage: %%prog\n%s" % __doc__)
parser.add_option("-u", "--username", dest="username",
                  default=None,
                  help="User name of DB Oracle ")

parser.add_option("-p", "--password", dest="password",
                  default=None,
                  help="User Password of DB Oracle ")

parser.add_option("-c", "--connectstring", dest="connectstring",
                  default=None,
                  help="Connect string for DB Oracle ")

parser.add_option("-d", "--dir", dest="dirname",
                  default=None,
                  help="Name of dir sql ")

parser.add_option("-l", "--log", dest="logfilename",
                  default=None,
                  help="Name of log file ")

(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
input_dir_sql = options.dirname
username = options.username
password = options.password
connectstring = options.connectstring
logfilename = options.logfilename

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s  %(message)s', filename=logfilename, level=logging.INFO)

logging.info('Start  script ')

sqlscript = ""
connectoracle = ''

currentDirectory = pathlib.Path(input_dir_sql)
for currentFile in currentDirectory.iterdir():
    sqlscript = sqlscript + "PROMPT Start script: " + currentFile.__str__() + "\n"
    sqlscript = sqlscript + "@" + currentFile.__str__() + "\n"
    sqlscript = sqlscript + "PROMPT Stop script: " + currentFile.__str__() + "\n"
    sqlscript = sqlscript + "PROMPT -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- \n\n"
    logging.info('Found  script:' + currentFile.__str__())

SqlQueryALL = Sqlheader + sqlscript
logging.debug("Sqlfile:\n" + SqlQueryALL)

my_env = os.environ.copy()
my_env["NLS_LANG"] = NLS_LANG
logging.info("Set AUTO_COMMIT="+AUTO_COMMIT)
logging.info("Set NLS_LANG=" + NLS_LANG)
logging.info("Set NLS_DATE_FORMAT=" + NLS_DATE_FORMAT )
logging.info("Set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=" + NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS)

connectoracle = str(username) + "/" + str(password) + '@' + str(connectstring)

logging.info("Connect ro oracle:" + connectoracle)
sqlplus_result = subprocess.run([r'sqlplus.exe', silent_sqlplus, connectoracle], env=my_env,
                                stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, input=SqlQueryALL)

#print(sqlplus_result.stdout)

logging.info(sqlplus_result.stdout)

logging.info('Stop  script')
```

Output for example

```
2020-11-16 21:24:41,831 INFO  Start  script                                                                                                                                             
2020-11-16 21:24:41,831 INFO  Found  script:C:\Users\Dmitry\PycharmProjects\count_char\sql\RunFirstTest.sql                                                                             
2020-11-16 21:24:41,831 INFO  Found  script:C:\Users\Dmitry\PycharmProjects\count_char\sql\RunFirstTest6.sql                                                                            
2020-11-16 21:24:41,831 INFO  Found  script:C:\Users\Dmitry\PycharmProjects\count_char\sql\RunFirstTest7.sql                                                                            
2020-11-16 21:24:41,831 INFO  Found  script:C:\Users\Dmitry\PycharmProjects\count_char\sql\RunFirstTest8.sql                                                                            
2020-11-16 21:24:41,832 INFO  Found  script:C:\Users\Dmitry\PycharmProjects\count_char\sql\RunFirstTest9.sql                                                                            
2020-11-16 21:24:41,832 INFO  Set AUTO_COMMIT=OFF 
2020-11-16 21:24:41,832 INFO  Set NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.CL8MSWIN1251                                                                                                                
2020-11-16 21:24:41,832 INFO  Set NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS' 
2020-11-16 21:24:41,835 INFO  Set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='.,'           
2020-11-16 21:24:41,835 INFO  Connect to oracle:scott/tiger@192.168.0.166:1521/test 
2020-11-16 21:24:42,777 INFO
Session altered.
Elapsed: 00:00:00.00         
Session altered.
Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
Start script: C:\Users\Dmitry\PycharmProjects\count_char\sql\RunFirstTest.sql 
View created. 
Elapsed: 00:00:00.00 
Table created.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Elapsed: 00:00:00.04
```