# how to execute multiple SQL files in oracle using one execute command?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I have multiple .sql files. How to create a single file to execute all sql files? I don't want to use a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

You'd create a "menu" .SQL script which calls other scripts using `@file_name`.

For example:

### a.sql

```
prompt Number of rows in EMP table

select count(*) from emp;
```

### b.sql

```
prompt Contents of DEPT table

select * From dept;
```

### menu.sql

```
prompt Calling A.SQL

@a

prompt Calling B.SQL

@b
```

### Execution:

```
SQL> @menu
Calling A.SQL
Number of rows in EMP table

  COUNT(*)
----------
        14

Calling B.SQL
Contents of DEPT table

    DEPTNO DNAME                LOC
---------- -------------------- --------------------
        10 ACCOUNTING           NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH             DALLAS
        30 SALES                CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS           BOSTON

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do concatenation of all sql files into one file.

Example for windows:

```
copy /b *.sql all_sql.sql
```

Example for Linux/UNIX:

```
cat *.sql> all_sql.sql
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's say I have 3 .sql files. So, to execute them all at once. You can have a single file like this:

```
SELECT 1
GO

SELECT 2
GO

SELECT 3
GO
```

You can just call that file, and it will call your multiple files.

Comment: I have script in which I have alter,insert and package creation scripts. Can we achieve this with above method? I am using oracle 11g. I have scripts like insert1.sql,insert2.sql,pag1.sql,pkg2.sql

Comment: Yes, this method can be used.

Comment: `GO`? In Oracle? I don't think so.

Comment: Yes I also think GO can be use in sql server, not in oracle

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64831787/how-to-sequentially-run-sql-scripts-oracle-automatically-using-python/64859764#64859764